# Can somebody explain exactly what this .htaccess RewriteRule does?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the following RewriteRule inside of a .htaccess file and I'm having a hard time trying to figure out exactly what it does.  Can somebody please dissect the following and explain what it does? Here is my full .htaccess file:

```
Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+[^/])$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1/ [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

This rule is trying to add a **trailing slash** to your URLs. But I must add that there is better way to write this rule.

Replace your rule with this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule [^/]$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [L,R=301]
```

Your rule can add a trailing slash to any file without a dot in it. So for example a filename called `/abcd` will be redirected to `/abcd/` and that would cause `404`.

Comment: I just tried using your rewrite rule and although it seems to work, it produces the following error in Firefox if I try using a url to a folder that doesn't exist:

    `The page isn't redirecting properly

    Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete.`

Any idea why I'm not getting a 404 error in that case?

Comment: I think there is some other conflicting rule as this rule works fine on my Apache. Edit your question with you full .htaccess so that I can investigate.

Comment: I edited my original question with my full .htaccess file code.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: Your edited question shows only one rule, is that correct?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.  That's the entirety of my .htaccess file.

Comment: Use Chrome dev tool with caching disabled and check in `Network` tab what URLs you're getting with 302/301 status.